# Trying to login to git from android studio gives a IpAddress loginbox

Tags: android, git

When i click login to github while in android studio it first takes me to IntelijIdea site and asks for permission which i clicked yes on and then it goes to a ipaddress and shows me another login box that i have no idea what to use as username and password on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use token for authentication like the image below:

[image]

just click on login with token and in the pop up showed click on generate button and it will redirect you to GitHub pages copy your token and paste it on the text input in pop up

Comment: Getting a popup saying that it is checking the url  and that never dissapears

Comment: It worked i had to pass it through the share to github function instead of add remote